# Including files in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to include a library - I've downloaded it and found exactly four files inside: 
.h
.lib
.dll
.def
I've put the header file inside of my project. That's the only thing I did - and the visual throws an error that it cannot open the .lib file.

So I immediately wanted to beg for help on stackoverflow, but I've decided to do a little research first. I've found out that the .dll file should be placed inside of the windows/SYSWOW64 location (for my 64-bit windows 7), I placed it there but VS still displays the same error.

How should I deal with that? Did I missed some step during the "installation"? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the path to the library (*.lib) in your project settings.

(You can put it also into your directory with sources)

The presence of DLL file during build is not required.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I set the path to the .lib file in "additional include directories" (properties/c++/general).

Comment: you have to add that to linker->Additional library directories, since this is not an include file but a library.